# Pandas .apply MemoryError and 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'apply'

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm trying to throw regex at a 500MB text file:

```
with open(f'{trn_path}text.00') as file:
       df_trn = file.readlines() 

re1 = re.compile(r'  +')
def fixup(x):
    x.replace('>', '').replace('<', '').replace('doc', '').replace(':', 
    '').replace('t_up', '').replace(
        'fi.wikipedia.org', '').replace('url="https', '').replace('\xa0','')
       return re1.sub(' ', html.unescape(x))

df_trn = pd.Series(df_trn)
df_trn = df_trn.apply(fixup).values.astype(str)
```

Gives me

```
MemoryError:
```

If I read the file chunksize

```
df_trn.to_csv(f'{trn_path}train.csv', header=False, index=False)
df_trn = pd.read_csv(f'{trn_path}train.csv', header=None, chunksize=chunksize)
```

I get

```
AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You never actually set `df_trn` to be a `DataFrame`, which is why you are getting the `AttributeError`.

Comment: `file.readlines()` doesn't return a data frame. Use a pandas read function instead, such as `pandas.read_csv` or `pandas.read_table`. Alternatively, you can use `readlines()`, parse the data and create your data frame from there using the constructor `pd.DataFrame(args)`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the code where I read the file chunksize. See above for update. Using pd.read_csv with chunksize returns a TextFileReader.